# Unclear about the meaning of the question

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I am reading Probability and Stochastics by Erhan Cinlar. I came across a question which I do not understand part of it. This is the question:

A function $f$ on $E$ is said to be elemenentary if it has the form $f=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{1}a_i1_{A_i}$ where $a_i\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and $A_i\in\mathscr{E}$ $\underline{\text{for each }i\text{, the }A_i\text{ being disjoint}}$. Show that every such function is $\mathscr{E}$-measurable.

I do not understand the underline part of the above question. Does he mean pair-wise disjoint, i.e $\forall i\neq j, A_i\cap A_j=\phi$? Does he mean $\bigcap\limits_{i}A_i=\phi$? Or some other intersection between?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does $\bar {\mathbb R}$ mean?  Aside from that, it's hard to imagine that $\cap A_i=\emptyset$ was intended.  If it were, we could let $A_i=A_j$ for all $i,j≥2$ and just pick some $A_1$ with $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$. And then let $a_i=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: The author must have meant that for every $e\in E$ there is at most one $i$ with $e\in A_i$. The words "for each $i$" stand loose form the words "the $A_i$ being disjoint".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that are pairwise disjoint, i.e. $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$.